# Remove option from dropdown menu

Tags: custom-options, ce-1.9.2.3

I would like to remove the 'Please select' option from a dropdown menu and assign my first option as the default option.

You can check it here: http://store.hbros.co.uk/beef-aubergine.html

I've already checked some tutorials but none of them works. What could I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before that take **Bakup**
you have to overwrite below file to remove please select for cutom option

`Copy \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php to \app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php`

Find below code:

```
if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
            $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']')
                ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));
        }
```

Replace it with

```
if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
            $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']');
               // ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));
        }
```

And you have done.

Comment: I don't have this folder "\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog", I have only "Customer" & "Eav"

Comment: first check this available \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php

Comment: Hi again. I access to the Select.php file and I comment the line "// ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'))"  and now it's done. You can check the result here: http://store.hbros.co.uk/beef-aubergine.html 

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Okay cool But don't edit core file it's not recommended one